# Possible Elasticsearch escape words

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to list out the elastic search escape words. 
I have tried and no luck to find how to get the escape words in elastic search.
Is there any option to get all possible escape words in elastic search ?

Comment: what do you mean by escape words ?

Comment: @ Kulasangar stop words other than default ones listed in elasticsearch website